# ios coredata would entity attribute change in new version results in crash

Tags: ios, core-data

I use coredata in my app for storing data. In my previous app version, it has some entities. Now I am doing the new version, and some attribute names and types of certain entities are changed. When I compile and run app in my device, it crashes and reports some error because the old coredata is not vilid anymore. I can solve this by deleting app from my device and re-compile and install it.

My question is, if the new version is downloaded from app store by user, would this change results in crashed in user's device? Because user would created some data and stored in older coredata. In addition, do I need to move the older data to new coredata, for example, an attribute name is changing from "photoId" to "picId",then would older photoId values be lost due to this change?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to you question is yes, that will crash at user's devices too. But there is nice mechanism to avoid that called Core Data Migration. There are a lot of articles in the Internet and at the Apple Documentation, here some of them:

1. [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration - Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)
2. [How to Perform a Lightweight Core Data Migration - Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration)
3. [Custom Core Data Migrations - objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html)